# compare permissions between files

Tags: bash, permissions, compare

Anyone had situation where they had to recursively compare permissions between two directories (permission of files and subs)?

I tried to make a log for each directory containing full name and permission because they are located on separate boxes. I just want to compare permissions, I don't need to know if file exist or not just permission

I'm using this on both boxes

```
find /tmp/ -printf '%M %p\n' | sort > t001.log
find /tmp/ -printf '%M %p\n' | sort > t002.log
```

Is there a diff function that only compares permission?

thanks for any advice

Comment: looks like the user that I was looking for never existed but eventually I will need such a script so I will post reply when I get around to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

perhaps swap the field positions first to simplify,

```
find /tmp/ -printf '%p %M\n' | sort > t001.log
find /tmp/ -printf '%p %M\n' | sort > t002.log

join t001.log t002.log | awk '$2!=$3'
```

will give the list of common files with different permissions.